# Error while doing Ionic build android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I have followed all the tutorials that is to be followed and done the settings correctly. I am getting the following error

```
[Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting setting it manually.
Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.]
```

Now possible solution to the problem is to add the path to your Android sdk in the **$ANDROID_HOME and $PATH** variable

Here is the output

```
echo $PATH
```

> /home/samyak/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_65/bin:/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_65/jre/bin:/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_65/bin:/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_65/jre/bin:/home/samyak/Android/Sdk/tools:/home/samyak/Android/Sdk/platform-tools

```
echo $ANDROID_HOME
```

> /home/samyak/Android/Sdk

as soon as I do android I get the gui of android.  I think I am missing something. If somebody could help me out

```
Version details
Ionic 1.7.11
Cordova 5.4.0
Android-sdk 23
```

Also to note that I did not download the Android Sdk but took it from a friend via hard drive? Will that effect my android build?

Comment: Please follow this tutorial ,https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/09/install-android-cordova-ionic-framework-ubuntu/ It will be helpful for you

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the Android Tools inside the path folder.After you have the `Android SDK` downloaded and installed, you need to install `build tools` for the version of android you're targeting.  You will need to check:

- `Tools`
- `Targeted Android API Version`
- `Extras`

and hit `Install` in the `Android SDK Manager`. If something is missing after this, install
   what build tool is complaining about.

Comment: I copy pasted my android sdk from a person in whose system it was working? Do we have to run some command to build? Because according to android sdk manager everything seems fine

Comment: What's the output of `ionic build android` now ?